# Story about a teenager who makes a homemade black hole which proves unexpectedly dangerous

Tags: story-identification

This story is probably from an anthology.  It involves a kid or teenager who is secretly developing a black hole in his room. Eventually things get out of hand.

I believe this was written in English.

Comment: "unexpectedly"...

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet - What kind of bumbling muppet has the smarts to make a black hole but is unaware of its destructive potential?

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet they have quite a bad fame, but [they are not that bad](http://hasthelargehadroncolliderdestroyedtheworldyet.com/)

Comment: OP comment below doesn't indicate 100% certainty but seems to agree this is likely the same story

Comment: @Otis Should we wait a bit then? Maybe OP will come back after having read the story.

Answer (score 5):

["Bobo's Star"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?94319) by Glenn Chandler. It's been collected in several places, with *Science Fiction Stories* being where most have found it as per [Collection of sci-fi/fantasy short stories: tiny aliens crashlanding in a backyard on Earth, growing a star as a school project, and some Le Guin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56157/trying-to-identify-some-short-stories/56178#56178) and [Scifi short story with a star in a jar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35649/scifi-short-story-with-a-star-in-a-jar/35759#35759).

Reviewed [here](http://casa.colorado.edu/%7Eajsh/astr2030_06/bhmovies.html):

> This children's story concerns a boy (Bobo) and his science experiment. Somehow he gets his hands on a Star Genesis Kit and creates a "pet" star in a protected, tough glass case, complete with an airlock via which Bobo can scoop sand into the vacuum, "feeding" his star in order to sustain itself. After feeding his star too enthusiastically, it finally undergoes a metamorphosis long after it should have burned out peacefully: it begins to collapse. When this fledgling black hole finally breaks out of its protected case, Bobo's uncle and a tray of tea cakes –along with half of Bobo's room – are the first to be gobbled up; Bobo himself only has time to imagine the headline "BOY DESTROYS UNIVERSE" before he is obliterated too. – Johann Greffrath

Comment: Found by searching for *short story teenager creates black hole in closet* and following the results.

Comment: I'm tempted to compare this to Dr. Seuss's _A Fish Out Of Water_.

Comment: I think that's it, but none of the links leads to the story itself.

Comment: @RobertGarner: Nope. It's almost certainly still under copyright, and it does not look like the author has put it out online. Do the details mentioned in the review match up to your memories?

Comment: Yes, the details seem pretty similar.  I think the boy was trying to be sneaky about it.